# How to use modules in modules

Tags: haxe, hexmachina

I'd like to have a module which can be developed in isolated envorinment but still remains a module which can be plugged into anoter project.

The idea: Currently I have state machine driven modular project where every module is defined by DSL so the main project has its context and command mappings and state machine. Now one of the modules will become essentially the same thing - it'll have its own context, its own child modules and its own DSL definition which will be separated from the main context.

- Is this possible?
- Is there some best practice of how to automatically forward events from the main context throught the module to the module context?
- Is there a way to map the modules private dispatcher as a dispatcher for the isolated context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It seems to be completely possible
- Since I didn't find any documentation or example regarding this use case I think there is no best practice
- As far as I understand it's possible to create own application context class which would expose possibility to override the context dispatcher. But it won't solve much because command triggers can only listen to modules and not to the whole context

So I assume that the best way to solve this is to create a separated communication module which will be mapped inside the "child" DSL and the "parent" module will then locate it through the core factory of the "child assembler" and trigger events through it. It also makes the communication more testable because that will channel entire communication through a single point where it can be easily tested/mocked/observed and it also abstracts away implementation and events of the "parent" application

Answer (score 1):

HexMachina only support one context by applications (parent-child context should be supported in future). I’m not certain to understand exactly what you want, but let start with few things.

### Communication between modules.

Modules have two dispatchers, one internal for all internal communication with FrontController, and one public for all external communication. 
To communicate between module, one module has to subscribe to the other. In DSL, it defines like that :

```
<chat id="chat" type="hex.ioc.parser.xml.mock.MockChatModule">
  <listen ref="translation"/>
</chat>

<translation id="translation" type="hex.ioc.parser.xml.mock.MockTranslationModule">
  <listen ref="chat">
    <event static-ref="hex.ioc.parser.xml.mock.MockChatModule.TEXT_INPUT" method="onSomethingToTranslate"/>
  </listen>
</translation>
```

In this example, when chat module `dispatchPublicMessage(MockChatModule.TEXT_INPUT, [“data”])`, the `onSomethingToTranslate(textToTranslate : String)` method of translation module is executed.

### Split DSL in many files

You can use context inclusion and conditional attributes to organize your DSL files by “component”, and define what you want to use at compile time.

```
<root name="applicationContext">
  <include if=“useModuleA” file="context/ModuleA.xml"/>
</root>
```

Conditional attribute value is defined by compiler flags (`-D useModuleA=1`) or directly in code check this [link](https://github.com/DoclerLabs/hexIoC#conditional-parsing).

### Driven many modules with the state machine

If you want driven many modules on one state change, you have used command to manage that.

```
<state id="assemblingEnd" ref="applicationContext.state.ASSEMBLING_END">
  <enter command-class="hex.ioc.parser.xml.assembler.mock.MockStateCommand" fire-once="true"/>
</state>
```

I hope this can help you. Let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: It doesn't really help me because I don't want to include the "child" DSL into the "parent" DSL... I already know the features you described (they're in the cookbook on hexmachina.org) and they don't really suite my needs as I want to develop the modules separately and later combine them inside a "meta" application which will only orchestrate the transitions between the modules. Also when I say "parent" and "child" I don't mean that they're inheriting from each other. It's more like "black box" sitting inside another "black box" where neither of those boxes knows that the other one exists.

Comment: btw: I tested the approach I described in my answer and it seems to be working fine.